# Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler with Maven - doesn't work

Tags: java, maven

I have set my pom file to ask Maven to compile my source code to be version 1.5 compatible using the `source` and `target` config params.  Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>user</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test</name>
   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And I have a simple main class like this:

```
package com.user;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        System.out.println("".isEmpty());
    }
}
```

`String#isEmpty()` was introduced since Java 1.6.  However, compiling my code with `mvn compile` works, while I would have expected it to fail because I have set Maven to compile my code to Java 1.5 and `String#isEmpty` was introduced in Java 1.6.  Could anyone please suggest what I might have done wrong?  What is the correct way to force Maven to use a particular Java version when compiling?

For information, I am using Apache Maven 2.2.1 and javac 1.6.0_19.

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the note at the bottom of the [compiler-plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html):

> Merely setting the target option does not guarantee that your code actually runs on a JRE with the specified version. The pitfall is unintended usage of APIs that only exist in later JREs which would make your code fail at runtime with a linkage error. To avoid this issue, you can either configure the compiler's boot classpath to match the target JRE or use the Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin to verify your code doesn't use unintended APIs

This means that although you're generating 1.5-level bytecode, you can still (unintentionally) call a 1.6 API method.  To flag these invalide API calls, use the plugin they mention.

Comment: That's a great solution but unfortunately it does not handle some other  API incompatibilities such as partial interface implementation. If you do not implement Iterator's remove() method it will compile under java 8 due to 'default' keyword in the interface, but won't compile under java 7. And this sniffer plugin won't catch that because that's not just an method call.

Comment: Here's an official guide on how to use Animal Sniffer and why: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-jdk14-on-jdk15.html

Comment: But is not he using `<source>1.5</source>` ? This should be giving compilation error ? [Here on -source flag in javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006155/usage-of-source-in-javac).

Answer (score 8):

You need to compile with a lower version of Java if you want it to not find `String.isEmpty()`. The source level controls language-level features you can and can't use, such as `@Override` on interfaces requiring compilation with source level 1.6. The target level controls the compatibility of the bytecode that compilation produces. Neither have anything to do with available APIs... that's all based on the classpath you use when building, which in your case includes Java 1.6.

Comment: Also, be sure that both your CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME variables point to the correct JDK version.  (I got hung up on this issue, and my JAVA_HOME was pointing to Java 6 when I needed to compile to 5.)