# Jelastic with Maven and Bitbucket

Tags: maven, maven-3, bitbucket, jelastic

when try to build source code on environment

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]

My pom.xml

```
        <properties>
         <java.version>1.7</java.version>
       </properties>

   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling Java 7 code via Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043042/compiling-java-7-code-via-maven)

Comment: i ask how to fix it in jelastic