# Java_home is 1.7 in mvn version, and in pom.xml, but getting error "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin"

Tags: java, spring, maven

My mvn -v prints the following :

```
>    Maven home: D:\apache-maven-3.2.1
>    Java version: 1.7.0_55, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>    Java home: D:\Java\jdk1.7\jre
>    Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
>    OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

My POM.xml is as follows:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.sample
    sample
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.8</mockito.version>
    <jackson.version>2.4.3</jackson.version>
    <jwebunit.version>3.2</jwebunit.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
    <jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
    <xml.api.version>1.4.01</xml.api.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <hibernate.validator>5.1.3.Final</hibernate.validator>
</properties>

<dependencies>

.....

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>AcmeWeb</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have removed the dependencies as it is a big list, and have given only portions that may be relevant here.  If required I can print the full list.

When doing a Mavan install from my eclipse IDE, am getting following error :

```
"[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project sample: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]"
```

Can someone please help me where I am wrong.

```
My JAVA_HOME is set to "D:\Java\jdk1.7\jre".
```

Thanks & regards

Yuva

Comment: Do you used the embedded or the external Maven in Eclipse?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043042/compiling-java-7-code-via-maven

Comment: Check what is the installed JRE in Eclipse settings, is it the same JDK 7?

Comment: Thanks for you response.  I was trying to import a maven project into my workspace and here am getting this error.  My JRE is pointing to JDK 7.  Please help me.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JAVA_HOME to point the installed JDK (Not JRE)

I mean your mvn -v should display as Java home: D:\Java\jdk1.7

Comment: Thanks Manmay, the JAVA_HOME was pointing to JDK1.7 home, but changed it to point to JRE as suggested in some of the solutions, now I changed the JAVA_HOME as suggested by you, but still the same issue.  Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: when you execute mvn --version are you getting the new path as JAVA_HOME in the result ? Please put the result here.