# Set Mavens Java Version

Tags: java, linux, maven

We're trying to upgrade all our systems to `jdk1.8.0_66`, including maven (running on jenkins).

```
[jenkins@zldinfra1 jvm]$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.6.0_24, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.centos.plus.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[jenkins@zldinfra1 jvm]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/java
[jenkins@zldinfra1 jvm]$ file /opt/java
/opt/java: symbolic link to `jdk1.8.0_66'
```

All a quick google led to is that I should change my `JAVA_HOME` to the desired Java version. As you can see above, it's set to `jdk1.8.0_66`, but Maven is using a completely different path.

**Question:** 
How do I change maven's `JAVA_HOME`?

**Edit:**

Following @Rottens answer, I manged to get maven running with `jdk1.8.0_66`, maven's `JAVA_HOME` being set to `/opt/jdk1.8.0_66/jre`.

However, I'm still getting the following error upon trying to Deploy (building works fine):

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project deployTest: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7`

In the POM the compile plugin is set up as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In my Jenkins Project config I specified it to use the `default` JDK and `Maven Version 3.2.1`.

Just noticed:

The Maven Version 3.0.5 (which I configured to use 1.8) does not appear in Jenkins. The Versions that appear in Jenkins are `3.2.1`, `3.1.1` and `3.0.4`.

Comment: Have you checked `/private/etc/mavenrc` and `~/.mavenrc` for overriding JAVA_HOME settings?

Comment: What is the output of `mvn --v`?

Comment: Does Maven also uses the same user `jenkins`? Good chance that `JAVA_HOME` is set differently for your Maven user.

Comment: @Patrick `mvn --v` outputs the same thing as `mvn -version`

Comment: @GergelyBacso I will look at that right now

Comment: @Martin if its shown in your picture then its ok. I have no permission to see pictures at my current location. sorry

Comment: @Patrick I exchanged the picture for text

Comment: @GergelyBacso I cannot seem to find mavenrc anywhere

Comment: That is an optional config. If you don't have it, that means it is not the one causing your problem.

Comment: Could you check under your project structure which java version is it using? Could be possible you have multiple java version installed on your machine and the project might be using the lower version while building.

Comment: @nullpointer There are multiple java versions installed, and it's most definitely using a lower version than 1.8 (which the JAVA_HOME) points to. In Jenkins it's configured to use the "Default" JDK and in the POM I specified it to compile for 1.7.

Comment: @Martin : Since the POM uses the java version 1.7 and compiles the project using the same which might not be present in the system. You must look into this once. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14043545/1746118

Comment: @nullpointer I've seen this question and looked, but as far as I can tell, the script just uses the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Comment: 1. _mvn script_ sample : `#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME:-$(/usr/libexec/java_home)}" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec/bin/mvn" "$@"`


2. update the maven plugin and change to
`<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>**"newer version"**</version>`


3. the pom reads `<inherited>true</inherited>` and I hope the parent specifications are not different..are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was resolved by uninstalling `jdk1.7.0` from Jenkins, only leaving `jdk1.8.0`.

Configuring each project explicitly to use `jdk1.8.0` did also work, but that's for maintenance reasons not what we wanted to do.

I don't know why letting Jenkins automatically choose `jdk1.8.0` to compile did not work, but that seemed to be the issue.

In addition I upgraded Maven itself to `3.3.9` and all the used maven plugins to their respective newest version. This did not affect the Maven build. It did however break our ant build.

I also upgraded Jenkins to run on Java `1.8` instead of `1.7`, which didn't have any effect (except for making compile times marginally shorter).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check your $PATH environment variable, I always set my JAVA_HOME in my .profile and then use it at the beginning of my PATH variable so I'm always sure that I'm using my jdk version of choice. somethign like this :

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk/jdk1.8_65
export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Comment: this seemed to somewhat work. Still not compiling, but the java version is now correct.

Comment: @Martin is your runtime also set to java 8?

Comment: @Patrick According to `java -version` it's set to `1.8.0_66-b17`

Comment: @Martin I don't know what the runtime has to do with compiling though. What does javac -version report?

Comment: @Gimby `javac 1.8.0_66`. Builds now work, but trying to `Perform Maven Release` still gets me the "invalid target release: 1.7" error

Answer (score 0):

Update the maven version of your system from `Apache Maven 3.0.5` to `Apache Maven 3.3.x`

OR

In your project pom make changes to adapt to system as :

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited> **//default set to true**
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Having upgraded to `3.3.9`, using the "default" option for JDK yields an `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. If I explicitly use "1.8.0" though, the release succeeds.

Comment: explicitly as? @Martin

Comment: Our jenkins has (or rather had) jdk1.7 and jdk1.8 installed. When using "default" it used 1.8, but failed. If, however you use "1.8" it still used that same jdk, but succeeded.